# Getting a cylinder mesh to curve

Tags: modifiers

I ma trying to get a cylinder mesh to follow a curve but it does not look to be following the path. Also when I move the mesh on the z axis it moves along the path the loops back on it's self. Any help on this would be great.
[image]

Comment: hello, please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: I shared the file. Let me know if it uploaded ok.

Comment: you need to share the link  ;)

Comment: https://pasteall.org/media/c/d/cd256347c3e041d85c50bad55c6db506.blend

Answer (score 1):

Put the object and curve origin at the exact same position :

- Select the curve and press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> *> Cursor to Selected*
- Select the object and press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> *> Selection to Cursor*

Move the object along the Y axis if you want it to follow the curve.

Comment: Thanks for your help.